# How do I get the Ender Dragon egg and what does it do?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

So I finally killed the Ender Dragon! As I was climbing the portal back to the world, I noticed that on top of the column there was an egg. So I attacked, mined, clicked and nothing happened, it just teleported away. What does the egg do and how do I get it?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The dragon egg does absolutely nothing (well, apart from eluding most attempts to pick it up). Put it on your mantelpiece to show them online.

From [Minecraft Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Dragon_Egg)

> To obtain the dragon egg, the player may push it with a piston, detonate it with TNT, or place a torch or slab under the block the egg rests on and then destroy that block so the egg falls onto it. It is possible for the player to hit one while it is still moving to the point it breaks, however this is difficult. Another solution, is that you can start breaking a coinciding block and then scroll over to the egg while holding the break button, in this case you will start breaking the egg instead of it teleporting on contact.

Answer (score 7):

The most helpful way and easiest way should be :

1. Break two blocks down next to it.
2. Then place a torch two blocks down but this time under the block the egg is on.
3. Destroy the blocks separating the torch from the egg so the egg falls down on the torch.
4. And Voila! You've got yourself a Dragon Egg!

Answer (score 3):

Place a piston facing the egg, place a lever near the piston, then activate the lever.  The egg should drops as an item.  I don't know what it does; I think it does nothing.

Answer (score 3):

Since other answers tell you how to get the egg, I'll tell you some of my ideas of what it could be used for:

### A Sign of Wealth

If you play on factions, or any other competitive server, displaying a dragon egg prominently has its uses. First, a invading group would say "Hey, that guy has enough armor/skill to defeat the Enderdragon!" That might cause them to stay weary of you.

### Currency

While this is sorta ridiculous, it could be used as a currency. Since it is impossible to obtain after someone already has, it is impossible to counterfeit (unlike gold or diamonds, which can easily be mined). However, the problem with this is you have only one.

### A Sign of Rulership

If a town has a king, this is a full-proof way to known *who* is the king. While this may not be needed if the king never changes, it might be useful if he does commonly. Since there is only one dragon egg obtainable, one player can use it as proof he is, in fact, king. The upside of this is that it's impossible to counterfeit.

### A Random Number Generator

Even though it is **much** easier to do this with pigs, for example, the dragon egg, when clicked, teleports randomly to a block in the nearby vicinity. While it is not practical, it could be used in a place like a casino, to add a bit of show to betting.

### A Computer

This last one is pretty stupid. It is *technically* possible to build a device that is based off falling sand breaking cacti which break signs, but with a dragon egg instead of sand. The reason this works is because a dragon egg falls just like sand.

Comment: I know this is a years old post, but I have to point out you mean "counterfeit" (as in to make a copy of) not "forfeit" (as in give up)

Answer (score -1):

Somehow nobody mentioned that dragon egg is also used in practice.

Due to a long standing bug it's possible to [break bedrock with dragon egg](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Tutorials/Breaking_bedrock#Method_2_2) falling in a lazy chunk.

Also if you have a lot of dragon eggs instead of one (which is possible due to [duplication](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6pjILKM92gQ) of falling entities with end portal), you can [drain masses of water](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qf6EadbumS4) away from keyboard.

Comment: Bug fixed in 1.13.

Answer (score -10):

Pause, click 'controls', look at 'pick block' and use the same letter to pick up the egg.
Note: Only Work on Creative

Comment: Did you even bother to test this theory?

Comment: I think the egg destroys itself if you mine it on creative(tested).