# Does the Ender Dragon egg ever hatch?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I've just defeated the Ender Dragon and a portal opened somewhere below it. on the top is an egg. I've managed to get it down by right-clicking on it but can you do anything with it? Does it hatch? Can you place in your inventory and spawn Ender Dragons?

Comment: [Related] [How do I get the Ender Dragon egg and what does it do?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/61900)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get the Ender Dragon egg and what does it do?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/61900/how-do-i-get-the-ender-dragon-egg-and-what-does-it-do)

Answer (score 10):

No, it doesn't hatch, and it doesn't act as a mob spawner. It's merely a trophy for those who figure out how to pick it up:

> To obtain the dragon egg, the player may push it with a piston or place any non-solid block (like a torch) under the block the egg rests on and then destroy that block so the egg falls onto it. It is possible for the player to hit one while it is still moving to the point it breaks, however this is difficult. If broken and not collected the dragon egg will respawn some where with in "The End".

According to the [Minecraft Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Dragon_Egg):

> They currently serve no purpose, other than as a trophy or decoration.

Comment: Yeah it doesn't hatch. not in **vanilla** minecraft.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot "use" it for anything other than decoration. It does not hatch nor does it spawn another ender dragon. They are merely a trophy/decoration.

Answer (score 2):

No, the Ender Dragon Egg is just a trophy for now. That might change, but as of 1.3.2 and the previews for 1.4, it doesn't do anything. The best you can do with it in 1.4 (and previews) is mount it in a nice [item frame](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Item_frame) for display over your fireplace mantle.