# Is it possible to merge the ender dragon and wither?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Is it really possible to merge the ender dragon and a wither to make a super boss? I've tried and still trying to make an ender dragon spawn by using the egg, bonemeal, endstone and 3 wither skeleton skulls but its not working yet. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does the Ender Dragon egg ever hatch?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/87668/does-the-ender-dragon-egg-ever-hatch)

Comment: You could make a wither ride the dragon with a correctly parsed summon command in a command block, but I feel like you are probably just asking about an urban legend you heard from a (lying) friend. You can't.

Answer (score 5):

No, short of mods you cannot merge the Ender Dragon and the Wither, there is no code in the game to do such a thing.

You can [spawn an Ender dragon with console commands](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/131690/is-there-any-way-to-spawn-the-enderdragon-in-minecraft-without-mods-of-any-kind) and you can summon the Wither in the normal way (see the same page).

They [should try to fight each other in normal Minecraft.](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Wither#Behavior)

Comment: Who wins in a fight between them?

Comment: Someone should **science** this for more accurate information, but from what I've seen online it's usually the Wither (because the Ender Dragon isn't really that dangerous if you can fly like the Wither can).