# How do you get rid of an Enderdragon egg in a creative server?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I was in creative and then I put an Enderdragon egg in the wrong place and I couldn't get rid of it. I kept punching it but nothing happened.

Comment: What do you mean "nothing happened"? Normally when you hit a dragon egg it jumps - you can't "break" a dragon egg. If you google how to pick up a dragon egg that might provide you with an answer.

Comment: @pppery I don't think that this is a duplicate of that question, this question seems to be about a problem in creative mode, the other question is more general (and probably about survival mode). In creative mode it is possible to punch a dragon egg to break it (I tested it in 1.14.3, this may be a new feature, though I doubt it). If you can't break a dragon egg by punching it in creative mode, then it's either a bug, lag, or there is some plug-in, or mod, which prevents you from doing so.

Comment: @bearb001 that means the 3-upvote answer is wrong or doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @pppery That answer has not been accepted, so it may not really provide an answer to this question, even though is has 3 upvotes. It is explicitly stated in the question that it's about creative mode and in an earlier version it also stated that it was a creative server.

Answer (score 3):

When you punch an Enderdragon egg, it jumps and teleports to a random place near the egg's original location.

There is way to get the egg as an item. The following method is provided by this [link](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/61900/how-do-i-get-the-ender-dragon-egg-and-what-does-it-do)

1. Break two blocks down next to it.
2. Then place a torch two blocks down but this time under the block the egg is on.
3. Destroy the blocks separating the torch from the egg so the egg falls down on the torch.
4. And Voila! You've got yourself a Dragon Egg!

With this method, you can obtain the egg as an item and put it somewhere else.

Comment: Does the piston trick still work?

Comment: Pistons are expensive.

Comment: Yes, I realise they are more expensive than a torch, but I was ust asking whether or not that method still worked

Comment: Yeah, I think that method still works.

Comment: As was correctly pointed out in the comments, dragon egg teleportation doesn't apply in creative mode, meaning that this doesn't actually answer the question.